Images getting 404 error on the Webpack React Micro Frontend Project
I am working on a React Webpack micro-frontend project using module federation. I am able to run the micro-frontend separately.
Host application is running on port http://localhost:3000/ and micro frontend application is running on http://localhost:3001. Images are on port 3001, and I added images in the 3001 component. On port http://localhost:3001, images are loading, but on the HOST app, images are getting 404 errors.
Expectation: All React components are in the MF app (http://localhost:3001/). I need to access all images from 3001.
If I add images to the 3000 port, then images are working fine. But I need images from port 3001.
HOST application webpack.config.js - HOST application port is: http://localhost:3000/
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const { webpack } = require('webpack');
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require('webpack').container;
const packageJson = require('./package.json');
const ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin = require('@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        hot: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(?:js|ts|tsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env'],
                        plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", require.resolve('react-refresh/babel')]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(?:css|scss)$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                use: [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: "css-loader", options: { sourceMap: true } },
                    { loader: "postcss-loader", options: { sourceMap: true } },
                    { loader: "sass-loader", options: { sourceMap: true } },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: false,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: false,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.scss', '.css'],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'),
        }),
        new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin(),
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            name: 'McmpCore',
            filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
            remotes: {
                'supportPotal': 'McmpPortal@http://localhost:3001/remoteEntry.js'
            },
            shared: { ...packageJson.dependencies }
        }),
    ],
}

Micro Frontend app webpack config and it's port is (http://localhost:3001/)
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const { webpack } = require('webpack');
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require('webpack').container;
const packageJson = require('./package.json');
const ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin = require('@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 3001,
        hot: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(?:js|ts|tsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-typescript'],
                        plugins: [
                            "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
                            require.resolve('react-refresh/babel')
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(?:css|scss)$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                use: [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: "css-loader", options: { sourceMap: true } },
                    { loader: "postcss-loader", options: { sourceMap: true } },
                    { loader: "sass-loader", options: { sourceMap: true } },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: false,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: false,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.scss', '.css'],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'),
        }),
        new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin(),
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            name: 'McmpPortal',
            filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
            exposes: {
                './SupportPortal': './src/App.tsx',
            },
            shared: { ...packageJson.dependencies }
        }),
    ],
}

Micro frontend component is where I added images
const Info = () => {
    return (
        <div className='home-info'>

            <div className={`info left ${TW_CLASS.BOX_SHADOW} `}>

                <div className='user-info'>
                    <div className='user-img'>
                        <img src={`/images/default.png`} className='shadow-md shadow-gray-400' />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h4>John Doe</h4>
                        <p>Senior Technical Executive</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className='services'>
                    <h4 className='mb-3.5'>Active Services</h4>

                    <div className='grid grid-cols-2 gap-4'>
                        <div className='active-services'>
                            <div>
                                <p><strong>Consulting Services</strong></p>
                                <p>Expiry Date: 12 Dec 2024</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><strong>Azure Managed Services - Gold</strong></p>
                                <p>Expiry Date: 12 Dec 2024</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><strong>Azure Managed Services - Platinum</strong></p>
                                <p>Expiry Date: 12 Dec 2024</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className='service-information-cards'>
                            <h6>SLA</h6>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Scope of Services to be covered</li>
                                <li>Perfomance metrics</li>
                                <li>Penalities for contact breach</li>
                                <li>Customer responsibilities</li>
                                <li>Service provide responsibilities</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div className={`info right ${TW_CLASS.BOX_SHADOW} `}>
                <h4>Support Portal</h4>
                <p>Text</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

